# How to remove gridlines using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to remove gridlines from excel worksheet which I created using openpyxl. I know that it can be done using xlswriter, looking for a openpyxl solution.   I Don't like mixing the two in my code. See code below is not working.  Any suggestive solutions?

```
workbook = load_workbook(OutFile1)
worksheet = workbook['Sheet']
worksheet.sheet_view.showGridlines = False
workbook.save(OutFile1)
```

Comment: capital 'L' -->worksheet.sheet_view.showGridLines=False